# A console to play them all

Tags: ps4, bloodborne, journey, marvel-ultimate-alliance

I have a list of some gaming titles, some old others a bit newer (some being PlayStation exclusives) that I'd love to get my hands on. Can any if not all or at least half of these be played on the ps4 pro? Or would it be better to just get a regular ps4? Which of the 2 can play the majority of these?

Here's the list.
Journey https://www.playstation.com/en-us/games/journey-ps4/

Bloodborne all DLC included

Rachet and clank https://www.playstation.com/en-us/games/ratchet-and-clank-ps4/

Marvel ultimate alliance 2 all DLC included. Where to find the DLC would also be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Every version of the PS4 can play all PS4 games. The PS4 Pro is a more powerful version of the console and can play many games at a more stable frame rate, with added graphical effects or at a higher resolution. However, all past and future PS4 games are still normally playable on the regular PS4.